# How can i address Error: attempt to apply non-function

Tags: static

This is my code
counts <- tiledb_scdataset$somas$RNA$X$members$counts$to_matrix(batch_mode = TRUE)
dim(counts)
I have this error:
Error: attempt to apply non-function
How can i solve this issue?
I have downloaded my data but have this error